# Spring Boot memory usage (JpaMetamodelMappingContext)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

We have Spring Boot Data-Rest project with more than 1000 JPA entities in it. Application starts with initial 4GB memory usage. When I analyze the memory usage via JProfiler, I can see BasicPersistentEntity classes and their propertyCache cover most of the consumption.

Is this the default behaviour, or are we missing something?

[image: jprofiler]

Comment: I can't help you to solve the problem but Spring Data analysis the entities to be able to generate the queries when using JPA repository interfaces. I hope on of the Spring Data JPA guys will see your question.

Comment: After JpaMetamodelMappingContext  initialization memory usage rising from 1GB to 4GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but it's fixed in Spring Boot 2.1.0.M3 version.

Here is the related commit.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/commits/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/mapping/JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java

[image: jprofiler]